# JQuery toggleClass on setInterval not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code:

**[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/00w2ythq/)**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('button').each(function(index){
    var time = index * 1000;
    setInterval(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('one two');
    }, time);
  });
});
```

This should cycle between two classes under the set interval time, but its not working. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code does not work because JavaScript is using a concept called lexical scoping. This defines how variable names are resolved in nested functions.

In your case `$(this)` is not what you think it is. `this` is bound to `setInterval` as you pass a anonymous function to setInterval. One of the most important concepts in JavaScript is how scope binds to "this".

#### Learn more about scoping

1. http://javascriptplayground.com/blog/2012/04/javascript-variable-scope-this
2. https://spin.atomicobject.com/2014/10/20/javascript-scope-closures

#### Working example

https://jsfiddle.net/00w2ythq/1/

```
$('button').each(function(index){
    var time = index * 1000;
    var button = $(this); // this is bound to .each()

    setInterval(function(){
        // scope changed, this is bound to window
        button.toggleClass('one');
    }, time);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code `this` refers the `setInterval function scope` and thus in order to reference the button you need to assign this to another variable

```
$('button').each(function(index){
  var time = index * 1000;
  var self = $(this);
    setInterval(function(){
    self.toggleClass('one');
  }, time);
});
```

**[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/00w2ythq/3/)**

Answer (score 0):

Inside setInterval callback `this` refers to `window` object not the element object. So either store the reference in a variable as in another answer and use it inside callback or bind the `this` context to the `setInterval` callback function using **[`Function.prototype.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind)**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('button').each(function(index){
      var time = index * 1000;
      setInterval(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('one');
      }.bind(this), time);
  });
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('button').each(function(index) {
    var time = index * 1000;
    setInterval(function() {
      $(this).toggleClass('one');
    }.bind(this), time);
  });
});
```

```css
.one {
  background: #000
}
.two {
  background: #f00
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="one">Button</button>
<button class="one">Button</button>
<button class="one">Button</button>
<button class="one">Button</button>
<button class="one">Button</button>
<button class="one">Button</button>
```

---

For older browser check [polyfill option for bind method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind#Polyfill).